# generating new page in ionic 2 error No ionic-angular package found

Tags: ionic2

when i type ionic generate page new-place
it shows as follow
No ionic-angular package found, do you have Ionic installed? (CLI v2.0.0)

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 3.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
```

plz give me suggestion for it

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion: if you used beta version of CLI you need to uninstall the beta version of the cli by running `npm uninstall -g ionic`, then install the latest stable version of the `cli npm install -g ionic` and try again.

If this is not working then use the second suggestion:

> 1- Remove ionic and cordova using these commands:
>
> ```
>  npm uninstall -g cordova
>  npm uninstall -g ionic
>  npm cache clean
> ```
>
> 2- Then, re-installed:
>
> ```
> npm install -g cordova
> npm install -g ionic@beta
> npm install -g n
> ```
>
> the two previous commands will install the last stable version of
>   node.
>
> ```
> npm install -g typescript 
> npm install -g typeings
> ```
>
> So the problem is all about the version of node, this solution worked
>   well for me, but I would like to advice you to try just the two
>   mentioned commands to install a stable version of the node if it works
>   for you then no need to remove ionic and reinstall it.

The second suggestion is a resolution from this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1370) on ionic-cli.

The third  suggestion: if you are using ionic 3.3 then it is Important to use the last version of Nodejs for now it is 6.10.3 
that is all possibilities. 
Good luck :)
 Thanks